# Labeling a list plot came from excel data set

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, import, excel

I have made a list plot for an excel data set and I got the graph. However, I need to label each graph by its name that is already in the first cell of each column. I have 647 rows and 21 columns, but here is a simple illustration.

As an example:
Suppose I have the following table from excel

```
 A                B               C              D
```

73.21428571     69.64285714      70.53571429    71.42857143
85.14851485     65.34653465      84.15841584    73.26732673
88.29787234     82.9787234       75.53191489    97.87234043
86.95652174     69.56521739      66.95652174    78.26086957
79.16666667     68.33333333      74.16666667    76.66666667
100             83.65384615      79.80769231    93.26923077
82.53968254     68.25396825      71.42857143    75.3968254
72.34042553     86.5248227       79.43262411    75.88652482
78.98089172     78.98089172      71.33757962    83.43949045
85.32608696     72.82608696      72.82608696    82.06521739

How I can label the `ListPlot` of the first column by A, and the same thing for other columns?

Comment: In fact, this is what I have done: 
`mutaz = SemanticImport["Faressystem.xlsx"]`
`mutaz[Transpose /* ListLinePlot]`
Then I got the graph. The imported file doesn't contain the first letters row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column headers are not part of the data import:

```
colHeaders = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
data1 = {{73.21428571, 69.64285714 , 70.53571429 , 71.42857143},
  { 85.14851485 , 65.34653465 , 84.15841584 , 
    73.26732673}, {88.29787234, 82.9787234, 75.53191489, 
    97.87234043}, {86.95652174 , 69.56521739 , 66.95652174, 
    78.26086957}, {79.16666667, 68.33333333, 74.16666667, 
    76.66666667}, {100, 83.65384615, 79.80769231, 
    93.26923077}, {82.53968254, 68.25396825, 71.42857143, 
    75.3968254}, {72.34042553, 86.5248227, 79.43262411, 
    75.88652482}, {78.98089172, 78.98089172, 71.33757962, 
    83.43949045}, { 85.32608696, 72.82608696, 72.82608696, 
    82.06521739}};

ListPlot[Transpose[Rest[data1]], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> colHeaders]
```

or, if column headers are part of the data import

```
data2 = Join[{colHeaders}, data1];
ListPlot[Transpose[Rest[data2]], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> First[data2]]
```

and, the way I always import data - into datasets and associations:

```
data3 = Dataset[AssociationThread[colHeaders -> #] & /@ data1];
ListPlot[Transpose[Normal[data3[Values]]], PlotRange -> All, 
    Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> Normal[data3[1, Keys]]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Mitch. I am just wondering, can we use the same code for `ListLinePlot`?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question I have a couple questions.  You show a first row of A, B, C,... .  Is that imported into Mathematica?  Or is it the EXCEL spreadsheet display?  If it's not imported then you can impute the first 21 letters as labels.  If it's part of the import there is a more simple answer, but first an answer to my question.

Comment: Yes it is. But the `ListLinePlot` that I need should start from the second row and all columns. I mean I need the list plot for the numbers and label each list line plot by its letter, List line of the first column by A, the second list line plot of the second column by B, ...etc. IF you have an answer for both cases, case if we don't import the first row of A, B, C....and the other case when we import the letters, that would be much appreciated

Comment: In fact, this is what I did: 
`mutaz = SemanticImport["Faressystem.xlsx"]`

`mutaz[Transpose /* ListLinePlot]`
Then I got the graph. The imported file doesn't contain the first letters row

Comment: I will give you several examples for your reference, but it's not at all clear to me from the sample data or your description, what you are after.  So, my response is dependent on my assumption of your needs.